# How to resolve the issue of file not found (even though it exists) on GCP's AI-Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

FileNotFoundError: File b'gs://text-recognition-modelling/Dhruv/cmle/eval_data_nott03.csv' does not exist

Comment: There is no information in your question where we can help you. Read this and try to improve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide more details? This error isn't enough for helping you.

Comment: Have you verified that the path provided to the Cloud Storage Bucket is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems like you are using pandas for reading the csv, try using some tensorflow method to read csv, it would work.